# Where is the icon for Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 20.04.4 located?

Tags: icons, location

I mean the diamond-shaped blue icon that has a couple of gears on it. I want to change it to something else, and have looked everywhere but have come up empty.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your comment. I mean the Ubuntu Software icon that appears as soon as you install Ubuntu 20.4.4.

Comment: That is actually the fallback icon: is also used when the proper icon is not found

Comment: So, can you tell me exactly where  this "improper" icon is located? I can't find it anywhere. Plus, it does seem a bit odd that on a fresh installation of 20.4.4, the system would be unable to find the "proper" icon. But I guess stranger things have happened. I just want to locate it so I can replace it.

Comment: Like you, I would need to search. Must be somewhere in the default icon locations, but could be hardcoded as well. Either the snap store in 20.4.4 is not correctly configured to retrieve the icon, or that icon is used intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the one located in `/usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32/mimetypes/` named  application-x-executable.png? (looks a little purple to me though)

edit: The blue one belongs to `Adwaita` not `gnome` as vanadium points out, both located in `32x32/mimetypes/`

Comment: The blue version belongs to the Adwaita set. It is by default installed with the `adwaita-icon-theme` package.

Comment: It should be easy to search for them, they all have the same name `application-x-executable`.

Comment: That's it! (in Adwaita/.../mimetypes) A little experimentation will pin down which resolution is being used, but that's no problem.Thanks a million for the help!

Comment: Note: In my case it was the one in Adwaita/48x48/mimetypes. Again, thank you all for your help! =:)